# How to fix this hover dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

The main problem is, i made 2 hover drop down items. 1st one is 5-6 buttons on the top menu and 2nd one is a hover drop down image. 
Now i don't know how to make a different CSS code for both of the objects. See my code you may understand.
I wanna fix the hover image on the top left. 
Here is the code:

```
code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4jgmo7k/

Note: Images are not working, but i wanna fix that "ffh logo" on the left top

Comment: Noone is going to download zip file just to help you. Set up a simple demo and post it here. http://jsfiddle.net, http://plnkr.co/edit/, http://codepen.io, ... or even build-in stackoverflow snippets will work.

Comment: Done mate, thanks.

Comment: reduce `top` in `.dropdown` class as you like

Answer (score 1):

You can add another class to the first dropdown menu. For example:

```
<div class="dropdown anotherclass" >
  <img src="images/ffhlogo5.png" alt="FFH Logo">
  <div class="dropdown-content" >
    <img src="images/ffhlogo1.png" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
    <div class="desc">FFH Logo</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then just select the new class in your CSS like so:

```
.dropdown.anotherclass {
/*insert specific css here*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw one more question- How can i merge different class of same thing in a single set. Example: i got many class of dropdown hover button like "/.dropdown" "dropbtn" etc? Or i should make a new topic for this question?

Comment: You can't 'merge' classes in CSS, what you can do though is group the CSS classes with the same attributes. For example: 
.class1 { padding: 0}
.class2 {padding: 0; display:block}

is the same result as: 

.class1, .class2 { padding:0}
.class2 {display:block}

Comment: Edit :Nothing, fixed it. Thanks, this topic can be locked :)